# Big-Oh notation theory, Exam perperation: Given This task, how can i calculate the big-Oh

Tags: big-o

I am revising for my exams of sorting and algorithm analysis and one of the past exam papers has the following question:

"I would like to be able to take all the letters in some arbitrarily long word
of N letters and nd the anagrams (real words that are made of the same
letters e.g. DOG and GOD)."

```
My frst approach is this:
Find all the words by
Picking a first letter (N possibilities)
Picking a 2nd letter (N-1 possibilities)
Picking a 3rd letter (N-2 possibilities) etc.
For each word
Check it against a dictionary
```

What is the O(?) of this approach in relation to N the number of letters?
Why?

My initial theory is that the process of picking a letter at random is going to be constant because it will take the same time to pick any letter so this would be O(1).

This applies to picking the 2nd and 3rd letters these will still take a constant time of O(1).

Now checking them against a dictionary will take O(1) as well, but this needs to be done for each word so it becomes O(n).

So my overall complexity would be O(n). I may have done something badly wrong here but i can see no nested loops so i can rule out O(n^2) and i cant seem to identity any elements that make it logarithmic so O(log n) is also ruled out.

Could somebody possibly provide an insight into this, and tell me where i have gone wrong.

Thanks,
Chris.

Comment: Uh, the question doesn't appear to be a full question... Is there more than the sentence you provided? Is the question by chance about finding all the anagrams in a word?

Comment: Calculation of the anagrams should be something else than O(n) I believe. If you initial word is "GOD", possible anagrams would be God, Dog, Go, Do, and so on, right? Or are only words of length n allowed, where n is the length of the initial word.

Comment: I have posted all the information that the question provides. This is how the question is presented to me, hence my confusion.

Comment: Wait, so it was literally worded exactly like that? And that's it?

Comment: Yup that is the exact question. The question before it is about Turing machines so there is no proceeding question. I can post a picture if you want?

Comment: If you pick each letter like that you will be checking all `n!` (n factorial) permutations against the dictionary, so you have a lower bound of `OMEGA(n!)`

Comment: Wow, in my opinion that's incredibly badly worded. Do you know if they're looking for all lengths of anagrams too or just ones the same length as the original?

Comment: only 3 letters are selected, so i assume a length of 3 for the string is the maximum.

Comment: If the dictionary is a [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), then a lookup costs `n` where `n` is the number of letters in the word, so the total time would be `O(n*n!)`, however if you have a Trie, you can do it a lot more efficiently by traversing the Trie and keeping track of how many of each letter you have left and then only traversing possible branches. That would give you a running time of `O(n*k)` where `k` is the number of anagrams.

Comment: It pretty clearly says "take all the letters" and find the anagrams.. GO is not an anagram of DOG

Comment: If the dictionary is a hash table, lookups can be `O(1)`, but then space is probably worse.

Comment: Since it is not stated, i am assuming the dictionary to be a sorted list, which i think accessing something in a sorted list takes O(n) time. Then again, i might be mistaken here.

Comment: What would happen if you counted the letters in the word, stored the dictionary as a trie, and then did a DFS on the trie, using the letter counts as a way of knowing where in the trie you can go?

Comment: @user3580294 The data structure for the dictionary makes a huge difference as to what algorithms you can use.

Comment: @YTowOnt9 True, I take back what I said. I don't know what I was thinking, especially since right after I started wondering about different algorithms for different data structures... Probably meant something more like "possible"

Comment: i dont think that stating the use of DFS is needed, all of the other questions for previous years (expect this once) have been fairly easy and you can say O(n!) or what ever the answer is without going into detail about several factors. I think the main thing here is that to get the letters/permutations it would be O(n!) and the look up is assumed to be O(1) so this can be ignored. I will ask my teacher about it when i next see her but i think O(n!) is the answer they probably want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the question

> "I would like to be able to take all the letters in some arbitrarily long word of N letters and nd the anagrams (real words that are made of the same letters e.g. DOG and GOD)."

you shall devise an algorithm to make all permutations of the input word alpha with arbitrary length n. The question suggests to take *all* letters, so only anagrams of length n are relevant for the answer.

If you use e.g. the QuickPerm algorithm, you have a time complexity of O(n!) I think.

Now you have to find out whether it is a real word. For this you use the given dictionary `dict` of all real words, which has a lookup complexity of O(1) and therefore has not to be considered.

So you have an overall complexity of O(n!).

Comment: Please note that I would give all the assumptions like the dict and the algorithm in the answer. Perhaps it would be best to have some small calculation which has the result of the overall complexity.

Comment: I always try to display my rationale in my answers. Thanks for your response Mare. I overlooked the fact that there will be n! ways of creating an anagram.

Answer (score 1):

Just wondering whether you could approach the algorithm slightly differently by searching the dictionary rather than all permutations of letter in the word

SO:
Count each letter in the word and total word length
(O=1, D=1, G=1) and word =3

for each word in the dictionary with length=3
  Do the letter counts match exactly

Which I think is O(n^2)

Comment: I think the optimization is in calculation of the permutations, not in the lookup. So you may be right as position of the letter in the word has no relevance for permutations. Calculation of a "weight" of the input word is a possible way to go. But your algorithm will not calculate something that is a good weight, so all three letter words would give the same result.

Comment: This would work and the running time is only O(n), but the constant multiplier is the size of the entire dictionary! Which could be huge, so it's not a very efficient algorithm.

Comment: @YTowOnt9 I do not think that there shall be a constant factor. You have to get different results for "AAA" and "AAB" to get the right set of permutations.

Comment: @MareInfinitus the constant factor is the size of the dictionary. You'd be iterating through the entire thing and checking every word to see if it's an anagram

Comment: @YTowOnt9 As I understand what is written in the answer, there should not be cycled through the whole dictionary, but the dictionary gives all anagrams based on a set of characters. Hence I thought a weight shall be calculated, which gives a unique number for any arbitrary set of characters. And the lookup is based on that number. e.g.: Input word: "GOD", calculated number: "DOG" (just sorted ascending), lookup gives results: "GOD, "DOG", "other words with that combination". This would be an overall complexity of O(n), given a dictionary with all real words.

Comment: @MareInfinitus I see. I interpreted the "for each word in the dictionary" as a way of looping through the entire dictionary.